# Raspberry disease

Tags: diagnosis, diseases

My Raspberry has got some disease. Please see the picture. Can anyone advise me on what is this and how to treat it?

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering where in the world you are Jacob - this plant looks as if its over wintered, some of the leaves have shrivelled quite naturally, but new growth is starting from the leaf joints. Have you just come out of winter? Did you prune this plant last year? How old is this cane and did it fruit last year?

Comment: I'm in Australia, in the end of the Summer. The plant is new, less then one year old and it gave just a couple of fruits.

Answer (score 3):

Following your response to my comment, I'd suggest that your raspberry suffered some drought, but is still healthy, evidenced by the new growth appearing at the leaf joint above, so I don't think you need to worry about its being diseased.